Display actual key order in VS Code in Debug mode (javascript)
In VS Code, in debug mode, when I move my mouse over an object, the keys are sorted in alphabetical order. Can VS Code be configured to display the keys in their actual order?

When hovering, I'd like the entries to be displayed in their actual order (b then a instead of a then b). Is this possible, and if so, how do I go about it?
On the Internet, I've been told to use console.log() but this solution is tedious, so I'd like it to be automatic on each hover.

Javascript objects are by definition a unordered collection of properties, so guaranteeing a order is not possible. Other data structures such as a Map can guarantee order (of insertion) though.

@nbokmans not really unordered nowadays, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/15452072 . But I would not recommend relying on object property order anywhere, that I think we can agree on. As for the answer, I would add Object.entries(obj) to watch

The ordering of properties is not even stable, as the order is defined by when properties were added to an object. Code should not be designed to rely on object property ordering.
